Is it not possible to import a cube with 36 (not 24) vertices from Blender into Unreal?
Background
I have been trying to import an icosahedron mesh into Unreal from Blender, in such a way that every tri in the mesh has 3 distinct vertices stored. This is so I can then do some maths on those tris, move every tri around separately, and the like.
But no matter what I try, Unreal won't give me the full set of vertices.

Simplified Problem
So I simplified the problem as much as I can by making a simple cube in Blender, with 36 vertices. That is: 6 sides, 2 triangles per side, 3 distinct verts per tri. 36 vertices.
It turns out I can't even get this cube into Unreal with all 36 vertices intact. I only ever get the 24 verts you might typically expect. 6 square sides, 4 verts per side.

Things I've Tried

The cube mesh in Blender has been:

Triangulated (modifier)

Edge Split

Mark Seams

Shade Flat

Triangulated again (on export)

In other words, everything I can think of to be clear that I want 3 verts per tri. This displays 36 verts in Blender before exporting.



Opening the exported OBJ file in:

Blender

Notepad

3D Viewer

... all state 36 vertices. Only Unreal still says 24.



Exporting with FBX gives the same result in Unreal.

With a much larger mesh (my icosahedron), I do get small differences between FBX/OBJ/the various import settings in which vertices exactly are discarded. But regardless of which verts and which approach, there are still always hundreds of vertices discarded from the icosahedron once imported into Unreal.

I have tried every import/export option I can think of in both Blender and Unreal.



The Question
I am getting the impression that no matter what, if Unreal finds 2 vertices in an import file with the same position and normal, it will turn them into 1 vertex... even when that means that once-separable tris become no longer separable.
So my question is:

Is is actually possible to import a mesh into Unreal while keeping all duplicate vertices intact?

If so, how?


Ie., How can I import a cube with 36 vertices from Blender into Unreal, while keeping all 36 vertices? Or is this not possible?
